# ¿Como llenar dinamicamente arreglos en php?

Tags: php

Quiero pedir su amable ayuda ya que soy novato en php.

Tengo las siguientes cantidades :

```
$xcantidad1 = 1 ; $xcantidad2 = 2 ; $xcantidad3 = 2 ; $xcantidad4 = 3 ;
```

Tengo un tope de 10 renglones.

Como puedo llenar los 10 renglones con las cantidades arriba mencionadas y con un total de 4 elementos ( columnas ).

Como esto : `renglon1 = [1,2,2,3]`

Perdon por preguntar algo tal vez tonto, eso seria formacion dinamica de un arreglo ?

Gracias.

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que los renglones tienen que ver en este problema. ¿Lo que quieres es simplemente inicializar un array con valores?

Comment: Gracias por tu amable respuesta, mira o sea necesito formar n renglones en este caso seria 10 ( este sera un valor dinamico ) y debe ser llenado cado renglon obtenido con los valores de las cantidades que serian 4 valores y por lo tanto 4 elementos del arreglo renglon. O sea crear dinamicamente esto : xrenglon1 y dentro tenga 1 , 2 , 2 , 3,luego el renglon 2 asi hasta n renglones. No se si me haya explicado

Answer (score 1):

> [...] O sea crear dinamicamente esto : xrenglon1 y dentro tenga 1 , 2 , 2 , 3,luego el renglon 2 asi hasta n renglones.

Una forma sencilla es usar bucles *for* donde limitar, tanto el número de *renglones* como el número de elementos. Después asignas los nombres de las variables en el momento de añadir los valores del *array*.

Quedaría así:

```
$xcantidad1 = 1;
$xcantidad2 = 2;
$xcantidad3 = 2; 
$xcantidad4 = 3;

$renglones = 10;
$elementos = 4;

for($i=1; $i <= $renglones; $i++){
    for($n=1; $n <= $elementos; $n++){
        ${"xrenglon$i"}[] = ${"xcantidad$n"};
    }
}

// para comprobar que la salida es correcta
print_r($xrenglon1);
print_r($xrenglon2);
print_r($xrenglon3);
print_r($xrenglon4);
//...
print_r($xrenglon10);
```

Se puede ver funcionando en [este ejemplo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c95a1fb489777edd869661e5f2afa4d14c2c56ce) (*enlace externo*).